# Migrate/map Wordpress.com blog to subdomain on a TYPO3 powered domain

Tags: wordpress, typo3

- I have a blog  `test.wordpress.com`
- I have a website powered by TYPO3  `www.mysite.com`
- I want to redirect(map) my wordpress blog to `www.blog.mysite.com`
- I want `mysite.com` to remain unchanged and my blog to be powered by `wordpress.com`
- Is there anything I need to do within TYPO3 for the migration to work? Do I need to create a subdomain in TYPO3 manually?
- Is following the wordpress advice - changing the c name suffice?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to map it via TYPO3.

It's better idea to use some redirect with your HTTP server (probably Apache) - most probably within some admin panel or `.htaccess` file.

That all I can advice now. Ask the administrator of your hosting for support with domain redirections. If it won't be possible you *can* do it in TYPO3 but it does not make a sense.